# How do you retrieve a users' access token and secret in ASP.NET 5 Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a small app that allows a user to login to the site with their Twitter account. Then, once that is done, I intend to use the account to perform various actions with the Twitter API. However in order to do this I require the previously obtained **access token** and **secret**, but I don't know how.

I'm using `.NET Core ASP.NET v5` on the boilerplate WebApp. Twitter authentication setup with:

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterOptions()
{
    ConsumerKey     = "BLAH",
    ConsumerSecret  = "BLAH"
});
```

How do I retrieve the stored access token and secret once a user has successfully logged in with the Twitter auth?

I assume it is something along the lines of `User.Identity.*` or `User.Claims.*`.

Comment: The key and secret come from Twitter, specifically from **your** Twitter account, not the user who is logged in.

Comment: Yes, as said in the OP I already retrieve that with the Identity auth setup. However I need the token and secret I've stored again later.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing that anywhere, especially not in a user claim.

Comment: But there is clearly some state that is saved once a user logs in via Twitter for the first time? Is that not the auth token?

Comment: Well yes, but the question is: what do you want to do with that token now you have it?

Comment: Well later on in the session I'll want to use, say, Tweetinvi to do some things on their API, which requires the user access token and secret IE: https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the values to the user's claims on authentication. In your Startup.Auth.cs, you'll need to add the following:

```
var twitterOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.TwitterAuthenticationOptions
{
    ConsumerKey = /* Your App's Consumer Key */,
    ConsumerSecret = /* Your App's Consumer Secret */,
    Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.TwitterAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:twitter:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Twitter"));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:twitter:access_token_secret", context.AccessTokenSecret, XmlSchemaString, "Twitter"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(twitterOptions);
```

Then, when you need the values, you can retrieve them via:

```
var twitterTokenClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ClaimType.EndsWith("twitter:access_token"));
var twitterSecretClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ClaimType.EndsWith("twitter:access_token_secret"));
```

These are actual `IdentityClaim` instances, though, so you'll need to properly null-check and then access their `ClaimValue` property:

```
if (twitterTokenClaim != null && twitterSecretClaim != null)
{
    // work with Twitter API
    // Token and secret string values accessed via `twitterTokenClaim.ClaimValue`
    // and `twitterSecretClaim.ClaimValue`, respectively
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks solid. And just to be clear - This is a recommended practice? I assume that the token and/or secret will be invalidated at some point so I'll need to handle any failure to auth with them, and then update them, etc.

Comment: Well, it's sourced from an article listed in the official ASP.NET Identity Resources, so I assume it's okay. These claims are set on auth. If the Twitter auth expires, they'll have to reauth again, so it's not really an issue. Also, if memory serves, the Twitter user key/secret is long-lived, and perhaps even permanent, at least as long as your app remains authorized. Requests are made via an HMAC signature that combines both the user's key/secret with the app's key/secret, so it's a *lot* more secure. Facebook, for example, just uses bearer tokens, so those need to be refreshed.